# Is it better to model data as a Single collection or separate collections?

Tags: mongodb

As an example, imagine a trivial "helpdesk" type app where there are support tickets, and the app supports multiple companies logging in and managing their tickets.

Given that companies won't interact with each others "Tickets"....

Is it better to have one collection of "Tickets" and query or is it better to create collections of Tickets per Company?

Comment: The answer depends...as ever, you have to take quite a few things into consideration like max doc size etc and in-memory operators etc.

Comment: @Sammaye max doc size does not seem relevant here...

Comment: @assylias ah yea read the question wrong

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things to consider here.

The first thing is pre-allocation of space. You will find a couple of threads on the mongodb-user group whereby the OP is confused about why their database is taking so much space when their data is taking so little space. This is because when you reach a certain point of pre-alloc within a collection it will create files 2GB in size by default, even if you are only using 100meg of that space.

Now imagine this pre-alloc pattern for 1000 companies; this quickly creates inefficient use of disk space and, in most of the threads, performance and cost problems.

The second thing to consider here is the nssize, which is 2GB maximum. This may seem crazy but what if you do have more than 3 million members (assume a company is a "registered user")? You will quickly use up the maximum namespace file size that MongoDB can give.

Also you will gain no benefit from the lock (on DB level) without splitting them out into separate databases, this of course creates an operational overhead in maintaining the database connections for each company.

MongoDB is typically designed to scale through a cluster rather than scale vertically and scaling vertically is normally considered a bad idea for large websites.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much time using mongodb, but I'll give some arguments so we can discuss it. I think you should create just one Tickets collection, for the following reasons:

- Creating a Collection for each company seems like redundancy.
- You will have to create and configurate a collection every time you add a new company to your system in order to create tickets, when in the other hand you will only have to create the company.
- I don't know how where you planning to create the link between your company document and it's corresponding ticket collection, but I think is more straightforward to create the link using the id of the company document with an idcompany attribute in the Tickets collection.

I think one of the reasons that might make you consider to create a ticket collection per company, is due to the large amount of data could decrease the speed of your queries (all the companies inserting to the same tickets collection). But the way you could counter this is creating a sharded cluster, using a compound shard key with idcompany and some usefull attribute from the Tickets document, this way is very likely that all the documents of a given company remains in the same shard, so the common queries will perform relatively quick.

Answer (score -1):

My $0.02:

By separating out each company into their own collections, or better, databases... it makes customer migration and individualized backups, restores, imports and exports much easier at the expense of making your code a tad crappier.

Isolating customer data may reduce your data storage requirements, as you won't need to embed the customer ID into every single document. Of course, with separate databases, most drivers will treat that as a separate network connection.

As with everything, there are tradeoffs.